# php mail() is not working

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I can't get the mail() function to work.
Do I have to make any changes in the cPanel.
Do I have to configure anything?

I was using the code below:

```
mail('abc@xyz.com','Subject sdsas','Random Message','From: zzz@yyy.com');
```

Comment: localhost or server? if server are you running a dedicate server or a simple hosting?

Comment: Server...
It was working on an another server 00webhost.com..
But I can't get it working now

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from
>   the Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for
>   composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a
>   MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the
>   localhost or a remote machine). Second, the custom headers like From:,
>   Cc:, Bcc: and Date: are not interpreted by the MTA in the first place,
>   but are parsed by PHP. As such, the to parameter should not be an
>   address in the form of "Something ". The mail
>   command may not parse this properly while talking with the MTA.

See: [PHP: mail - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

[How can I get PHP mail() to work? Need help configuring a MTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083297/how-can-i-get-php-mail-to-work-need-help-configuring-a-mta)

[MTA for receiving mails, in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861389/mta-for-receiving-mails-in-php)

Both questions are dealing with MTA, it may be good to know if the hoster fulfills the requirements needed to send mails by using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following---

```
<?php

$to = "abc@xyz.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$msg= "Random Message";
$headers = "From: zzz@yyy.com";

mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);

?>
```

It will not work on the localhost. It will work only on the server.

It will help you.